# How can I have my values print under the specific column of ASCII(char), ASCII(int), and Hex

Tags: java, alignment

The code is displaying and converting the values I need, but it is not displaying under the correct column. They are all printing out under the initial column underneath what I entered. I entered K1 and it printed out the `ASCII(char), ASCII(int)`, and `Hex` properly I just can't figure out how to align them correctly. The image I have shows the output example.

```
/****************************************************************************
GMUnit3Ch12.java
Melissa Goslin
 *
This program will get input for a string, then output the initial character,
ASCII values of the characters and number, and hex values of each character. 
 ****************************************************************************/
import java.util.Scanner;      // import scanner

public class GMUnit3Ch12 {                      

    public static void main(String[] args) {     // main method

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);  // scanner

        String input;  // user input
        char output;   // variable to print out in initial column
        String values1; // variable used to convert
        String hexString; // converting to hex

        System.out.println("Please enter a string of any length: ");   // ask input from user
        input = stdIn.next();

        System.out.println("\t"); //space to separate
        System.out.println("Initial\tASCII<char>\tASCII<int>\tHex"); // headings 

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            output = input.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(output);          // prints out input separately in initial column

            if(Character.isDigit(output))    // if/else statement to see if value is a digit
            {
                System.out.println((int)output); // prints out ASCII (int)  
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println((int)output);  // prints out ASCII (char)
            }

            hexString = Integer.toHexString((int)output);   // converts to hex
            System.out.print(hexString.toUpperCase());     //Prints Hex String in upper case
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("\nThank you for playing!"); // thanks for playing!
    } // end main
} // end class GMUnit3Ch12[Below is an image of my output][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `System.out.print` and  some tab characters `'\t'` as below -

```
            if(Character.isDigit(output))    // if/else statement to see if value is a digit
            {

                System.out.print("\t\t"+(int)output); // prints out ASCII (int)

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("\t\t"+(int)output);  // prints out ASCII (char)
            }

            hexString = Integer.toHexString((int)output);   // converts to hex
            System.out.print("\t\t"+hexString.toUpperCase());     //Prints Hex String in upper case
            System.out.println();
            }
```